# Make List Of Divs Sortable & Clickable

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Can one make a list of `div`'s sortable/draggable, yet in the time if I click on one of the `div`'s in the list it performs a `.show('div')` jquery function?

Please help

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/736.cfm

Answer (score 0):

The [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has [draggable and sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable) interactions.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just got through with doing that. I created my own plug-in using the jquery-ui methods, sortable() and portlet(). Here is my code:

```
(function($){
$.fn.jSortable = function(){

    var element = this;
    var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function(){
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    };

    $(element).find("div.odd").addClass("odd2");
    $(element).find("div.even").addClass("odd2");
    $(element).find("div.job-items-block").hide();

    $(element).sortable({
        distance: "30"

    });

    $(".full-job-portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix")
        .find(".odd2")
            .addClass("ui-widget-header")
            .end()
        .find(".job-items-block");

    $(".odd2").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".full-job-portlet:first").find(".job-items-block").slideToggle();
    });
    $(element).disableSelection();
};

})(jQuery);
```

then in my html i put in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jobTable').jSortable();
});
```

hope that helps.